# Pointer to a function with variable arguments number

Tags: c++, pointers

I have declared:

```
class aaa {
public:
    static std::queue<QPair<void (*)( ... ), int> > m_commands;
    static int bbb();
    static void ccc(...);
};
```

and in bbb() method I wrote:

```
int aaa::bbb() {
    m_commands.push( qMakePair( aaa::ccc, 0 ) );
}
```

but it complains about:

```
error C2664: 'void std::queue<_Ty>::push(QPair<T1,T2> &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QPair<T1,T2>' to 'QPair<T1,T2> &&'
```

why? When I had function like that:

```
void reg( void ( *invoker )( ... ), int args  ) {
    m_commands.push( qMakePair( invoker, args ) );
}
```

I could easily send to the above function a static function this way:

```
reg( aaa::ccc, 0 );
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that passing a no-arg function pointer to that `reg` function *doesn't* compile; see http://ideone.com/gf8J3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qMakePair( aaa::ccc, 0 )` is (presumably) returning a value of type `QPair<void (*)(), int>`, since it doesn't know that you want a value of type `QPair<void (*)( ... ), int>`.  Invoke it explicitly as `qMakePair<void (*)( ... ), int>( aaa::ccc, 0 )` or `reinterpret_cast` `aaa::ccc` to the desired function pointer type.

Not to mention that this is (almost certainly) *illegal*, as `aaa::ccc` does not have the correct signature and cannot be invoked through the function pointer type you're using.

Comment: Whilst the pointer conversion is valid, attempting to dereference that pointer (i.e. call the function) leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes; AIUI it's legitimate to cast it back to the correct type and then indirect-call it.

Comment: Yes, that would be valid (although a little unorthodox!).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am sorry guys! Take my apologize. There was a bug in the post, I changed ccc( ... ). Now it compiles http://ideone.com/0vxpi  anyway the explicitly invoking (qMakePair<void (*)( ... ), int>( aaa::ccc, 0 )) worked for me.

Comment: @ecatmur but now there's written ccc( ... ) as the m_commands wants, so why do I have to use qMakePair explicitly with template arguments?

Comment: @tobi: You don't. Have you tried using it without template arguments after fixing the typo?

Comment: @AndreyT yes I did. And The error occures from my post, but I bet I did something wrong again... anyway it is solved. Thanks.